# How to stop a non-responding mainwindow in pyqt5 due to long loops with a push button?

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt5, kill, qthread

**Problem** I have a long running loop in pyqt5. While running, the mainwindow is not responding due to long loop.

**What I want** I want to have a STOP pushbutton to kill that loop. This button should still get active while the loop is running and when I press that it would stop the loop or kill the running.

**My Code**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def print_this(self):

        to_loop = 10000000
        for n in range(to_loop):
            print(n)

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(329, 205)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")

        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 60, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setText('Start Loop')
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.print_this)
        self.pushButton.show()

        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 60, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton_2.setText('Stop')
        self.pushButton_2.show()

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**My Attempt** I believe it has something to do with `multiprocessing, qthread, qprocess` but I couldn't just integrate it with my code. Appreciate your help. Thank you!

P.S please respond in one .py solution as I have so much codes in my actual workings. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use QThreads at all, instead you need to use QProcess. You can kill the QProcess with your Stop button and start other QProcess with your Start Loop button, this allows you to use your GUI while your loop is running. I also added a print function if you need to see the output of your script.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import sys
#path of your for loop script
user_script = "insert your loop path"

class Ui_MainWindow(QtCore.QObject):
    
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(329, 205)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")

        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 60, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setText('Start Loop')
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.start_loop)
        self.pushButton.show()
        
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 60, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton_2.setText('Stop')
        #stop loop when push button
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.stop_loop)
        self.pushButton_2.show()

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        
        #create process
        self.process = QtCore.QProcess()
        self.process.setProcessChannelMode(QtCore.QProcess.MergedChannels)

    def start_loop(self):

        self.process.start("python", ["-u", user_script])
        
    def stop_loop(self):
        self.process.kill()
        #this prints the output
        output = self.process.readAll()
        output = str(output.data(), encoding = "utf-8")
        print(output)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

And your "user_script" is a simple Python script with the following loop:

```
to_loop = 1000000
for n in range(to_loop):
    print(n)
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response. How to insert the loop path??

Comment: You can put the loop script in the same folder of your GUI application. Check the method `def start_loop(self)` it calls a process which opens your `user_script` and that script contains your loop. In other words, just change `user_script` for your loop path.

Comment: Sorry I'm having trouble understanding it. Can you please answer that by recoding it?

Comment: Check the upper part of the code, you will see the following variable `user_script = "insert your loop path"`, put your loop script path there. You need two `.py` scripts, one contains your GUI and the other contains your for cycle loop.

Comment: i see, is there anyway to show that in only one .py? so all the codes are in there?

Comment: `self.process.start()` does not allow methods as argument, so you will need to research by yourself another way to do that in one `.py`. If the answer helped you, can you mark it as correct answer? thanks.

Comment: I appreciate your response really. But I need an answer that is only in one .py because I have so much codes in my actual workings and the should be "two .pys" in my work have variables/pyqt signals that calls one another so I need a straightway solution. Hope u understand. Thanks.